# How to detect CJK Characters in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am receiving an XML as an input to my flex application from database via HTTPService call, now this xml may have some CJK (Chinese, Japanese & Korean) characters, I need to detect the presence of either of these characters and make some decisions in my application. The xml generally has english characters but may have CJK.

Please advise how can we achieve this in flex.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the string and look at each character:

```
for (var i:int=0; i<mySting.length; i++){
    var thisCharacterCode:Number = myString.charCodeAt(i);
    // now look at the code and see if it is a CJK
}
```

For reference... all of the unicode characters for CJK can be found here [Unicode Character Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)